# (鉑) string functions and UTF8 in php

Tags: php, utf-8, internationalization, multibyte

Why is the output of the following statement 3 and not 1?

```
echo mb_strlen("鉑");
```

Thing is that

```
echo "鉑";
```

will properly output this sign which is encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Just a thought, but I presume you've tried `mb_strlen('鉑', 'UTF-8');`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you set the proper internal encoding:

```
<?php
echo mb_internal_encoding() . '<br />';

echo mb_strlen('鉑', 'utf-8') . '<br />';
echo mb_strlen('鉑') . '<br />';

mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
echo mb_internal_encoding() . '<br />';
echo mb_strlen('鉑') . '<br />';

// ISO-8859-1
// 1
// 3
// UTF-8
// 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You will likeliy need to add the character set:

```
  echo mb_strlen("鉑","utf-8");
```

Comment: Just like middaparka suggests ;)

Answer (score 3):

Set the encoding to your mb_strlen function:

```
echo mb_strlen("鉑", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do the following, you will get the correct answer

```
echo mb_strlen("鉑", "UTF-8");
```

I'm guess php is defaulting to ASCII which produces an answer of 3.  I also found a very interesting article on Encoding for anyone interested in why and how it works.
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html